# How to make webpage show specific database item?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm trying to make the website link such that when I click on the thumbnail, it will bring me to another page. However, the details will be displayed based on the `itemID` I get in `browser.html`. How do I do that?

My result just ended me up with ALL of database results. I have also done the getdetails function so it works. MySQL variables are .item at the back of the variable declaration. My route for the SQL is `/details/:itemID`

```
function displaythumbs()  
{    
    var table = document.getElementById("DetailsTable");
    console.log("details_array is => ", details__array)

    table.innerHTML = ""; 
    totalDetails = details_array.length; 

    for (var count = 0; count < totalDetails-1; count++) 
    {                    
            var itemID = details_array[count].itemID;
            var thumb = details_array[count].thumb;   

            var cell = '<div class="container-fluid>' +                          
                            '<div class="rightside" >' +              
                                '<div class="right-left" style="margin-left:1%;">' +
                                        '<a id="details" href="details.html">'+
                                            '<img class="thumbstyle img-thumb" src=' +thumb+ ' />'+
                                        '</a>'+
                                '</div>'+                              
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>'; 
             table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cell);           
    }    
}
```

in my details.js

```
function displaydetails()  
{    
    var table = document.getElementById("detailsTable");

    table.innerHTML = "";      
    totalDetail = details_array.length;
    for (var count = 0; count < totalDetail; count++) 
    {                    
            var itemID = details_array[count].itemID;
            var Hyperlink = details_array[count].HyperLink;   
            var name = details_array[count].itemName;
            var ratings = details_array[count].Ratings;
            var picture = details_array[count].picture;
            var picture2 = details_array[count].picture2;

            var cell = '<div class="overall">' +                          
                            '<div class="leftside"' +
                                '<div class="centertop">' +
                                    '<h1 id="name"><u>' + name + '</u></h1>'+
                                    '<div class="starratings" style="margin-right: 10%; margin-left: 10%; font-size:25px;">'+
                                        '<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>'+
                                        '<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>'+
                                        '<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>'+
                                        '<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>'+
                                        '<span class="fa fa-star checked" style="margin-right: 1%;"></span>'+ratings+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="visitwebsitelink" id="hyperlink">'+
                                        '<a href='+Hyperlink +' />'+'<h3 style="color: black;"><u><i>Visit Website</i></u></h3>'+
                                        '</a>'+ 
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '<div class="fontstuff">'+
                                    'Recent Reviews'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>' +

                            '<div class="rightside">'+
                            '<div class="itemimg>'+
                                '<img src='+ picture + ' />'+
                                '<img src='+ picture2 + ' />'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'; 
             table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cell);            
    }    
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be making a call to a server anywhere. Where does your database live? You can't have a database on the client side

Comment: Im using Xammp to connect to my database server. So basically, i have routes and database script for my codes to link to my database. I have testing the routes using this application call Postman. I was able to get my data and have checked through using console.log. What I do not understand is how does one implement the itemid such that the it can substitute into details/:itemID :D

Comment: Where are you fetching the data in `details_array` from database?

Comment: So i have a app.js where i have declare the details_array to be an empty list. I also wrote a function using request, so whenever my quotes call for the details, the details from the database will be all loaded into this array.